# regex Using dot star in lookaheads;

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using lookaheads to see if the string contains both words.
I made it work using

```
(/(?=.*festival)(?=.*math)/).test(n);
```

But it doesn't work by leaving out the `.*` :

```
(/(?=festival)(?=math)/).test(n);
```

Why is the `.*` needed in all my lookaheads?

Comment: What strings are you testing against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look-ahead is a zero-width assertion that the characters *immediately following* the look-ahead match the expression.

`(?=festival)(?=math)` would only match a string which begins with *both* `festival` and `math` as the first characters, which is obviously impossible.

Answer (score 3):

`(?=festival)(?=math)` when used together will check if a string begins with both `festival` and `math` which isn't possible.

When you use `(?=.*festival)` or `(?=.*math)` you are checking the occurrence of the words in the string, not necessarily at the beginning.

The `*` is used to match a character 0 or more times, so `.*` is used to match any character in the string 0 or more times till the word you are looking for, in this case festival/math is reached. 
[Check this](https://regex101.com/r/lG8fV4/1) and [this](https://regex101.com/r/lG8fV4/2).